# Using jquery button to execute JavaScript .setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Hi Everyone I'm trying to implement a timer, that decreases in minutes and seconds based on using the .setTimeout(). Before you answer you should know, I've been on several questions and tried several implementations and nothing has worked. Below is the code:

```
  $("#start").click(function(){

var time = workTime.text();
timer.text(time + ":00");
time *= 60000;
console.log(time);
while(time !== 0){
time -= 1000;
setTimeout(takeSec, 1000);
}
});

function takeSec(){

   conosole.log("Timer Started");
var timeText = timer.text();
var minute = timeText.slice(0, timeText.indexOf(":"));
var second = timeText.slice(1);


if (second == "00") {
  minute--;
  timer.text(minute + ":59");
} else {
  second--;
  timer.text(minute + second);
}

}
```

Edit: Sorry I didn't explain the behavior of the code. So when the button is clicked all the about code runs, time always gets subtracted from, but setTimout(), is not working.

Comment: You should explain how the current code is functioning versus your expected end result.

Comment: Added it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is a little tricky but I think [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/k055ctzt/) is what you're looking for.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var workTime = document.querySelector('#work-time');
var timer = document.querySelector('#timer');
var timerRef, time;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
 clearTimeout(timerRef);
  time = +workTime.value || 0;
  timer.innerText = `${pad(time, 2)}:00`;
  time *= 60000;
  console.log(time);
 takeSec();
}, false);

function pad (num, size) { return ('000000000' + num).substr(-size); }

function takeSec () {
  console.log("taking second");
  var timeText = timer.innerText;
  var minute = timeText.slice(0, timeText.indexOf(":"));
  var second = timeText.slice(timeText.indexOf(":") + 1, timeText.length);
  console.log(timeText, minute, second);
  
  if (second == 0) {
   minute--;
    timer.innerText = `${pad(minute, 2)}:59`;
  } else {
   second--;
    timer.innerText = `${pad(minute, 2)}:${pad(second, 2)}`;
  }
  
  time -= 1000;
  
  if (time > 0) {
   timerRef = setTimeout(takeSec, 1000);
  } else {
   timer.innerText = 'DONE';
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="timer"></p>

<input type="text" id="work-time">

<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I haven't tried it yet, but I will let you know when i do. Looking at it, I kind of understand your logic, but I can't tell what I was doing wrong.  I would really like to learn how to use the setTimeout function properly.

Comment: Take a look at the jsfiddle link in my answer to see it in action

Comment: So when I ran the jsfiddle everything was working fine. But when I tried to run it on codepen, it didn't work, it had a similar error to when I tried to run my own code. It won't display the numbers, and I feel like its just not running .setTimeout(). This is the pen link:  http://codepen.io/mahn00b/pen/VjzKaZ.

Comment: If you change `+workTime.value` to `+workTime.innerText` then your codepen will work. `.value` will only work for things like `<input>` but you have an `<h2>` tag so you need `.innerText`